# How Do I Share A File With Other Users?

Tags: shared-folders, password-recovery

I am using ubuntu 12.04 lts and i shared a file call SET. When I Open The GUI, and click on browse network and press HARSHITA-HP-PROB it takes me to [image: This]

Then i press SET and it asks for a password which I do not remember :(

How Do I Change The password

I have root and admin privileges

Comment: I dont have windows 
i only use ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

do you have the use name of the user???? if you have then login as root
and type `passwd` and user name then it will ask for a new password by this way you can reset it.

like

```
passwd abd
```

Comment: Thank you but that did not help
I shared it and i know my password
It is not accepting my password
by the way, the user is jatin